# C# nameof of generics with constraints on type

Tags: c#, generics

Given class:

```
public interface ITest
{
    DateTime DataIns { get; set; }
}
```

And given the class:

```
 public abstract class ATest<T> where T : class, ITest
 {
    public void Test() {

          // I would like to do this:
         // var field = nameof(T.DataIns);
    }
 }
```

Is it not possible to get the `nameof` interface property without using the interface itself? I know that, of course, is possible to do that `var field = nameof(IMetrics.DataIns);` , but I would like to refer to the generics type.

Comment: If you can't do it, it's likely that it's not possible

Comment: Looks like it is unlikely to happen: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/810

Comment: I don't think it's possible, class ATest<T> might not have property DataIns at all, e.g.

class ATest {

  DateTime ITest.DataIns { get { return DateTime.MinValue; } set {}}
}

Comment: Why would you like to refer to the generic type? What difference does it make?

Comment: @Sweeper because I don't want to make inconsistent my code. I don't want to use the interface reference all over my generics code.

Comment: As you have constraint as "ITest", that means all  "T" will be of type "ITest". You cane use interface "ITest" to get the property name
var field = nameof(ITest.DataIns);

Comment: @Shashi the two things are not connected. I can also write `var field = nameof(IAnotherInterface.SamePropertyNameDataIns)`. The constraint on type T it's not applied to the line of code nameof.

Comment: @briantyler yes exactly the same thing. Ok, maybe I just have to avoid it for now and check if in future this will be possible. Thank you. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @sintetico82 if you do like this var field = nameof(IAnotherInterface.SamePropertyNameDataIns). you will violate Liskov Substitution principle

Comment: @Shashi, maybe I didn't explain it well, I want exactly avoid to do that

Comment: You can cheat, `T x; var field = nameof(x.DataIns);`

Comment: @sintetico82 added the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is unlikely to happen: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/810

You can cheat a bit and go via something that generates a `T` symbol, since `nameof` is a compile-time construct. In some sense this is better than coding against the interface as it does the right thing at compilation, however that's more a matter of opinion.

```
public abstract class ATest<T> where T : class, ITest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var field = nameof(THack.DataIns);
    }

    static T THack => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Considering that this can be done, it is a bit silly that you cannot use `T` directly.

Comment: You can use a local variable as well, `T x; var field = x.DataIns;`